# Zend_Auth and dynamically changing user details on the UI

Tags: php, zend-framework

When my users are logged in I display their details (name, email) on the UI.  When they update their profile, I would like to show the *updated* details, without requiring the user to log out and back in.

The UI details are retrieved from Zend_Auth via a view helper.  Zend_Auth is storing the 'identity' details in a session.

How should I go about updating the details in the session?:

- I was considering retrieving the user's login credentials from the database and using them to call Zend_Auth->authenticate() again.  The problem is that I don't know the password, only it's md5 hash.  I could consider a new method, reauthenticate(), which configured the adapter to bypass the md5 and salt, but this sounds laborious.
- I was considering writing directly to the Zend_Auth session namespace, but this sounds like a recipe for trouble?

Have you come across a similar problem?  How did you handle it?

Your ideas are much appreciated!

Comment: So you're using email as the identity, and loading name from the database in your helper?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's how I solved the problem for the time being.  Not sure yet if it's the best solution:

- create a wrapper for Zend_Auth
- include a getAuthAdapter($raw) method
- configure the adapter differently, depending on the value of $raw

  ```
  if (false === $raw) {
      $this->_authAdapter->setCredentialTreatment('SHA1(CONCAT(?,salt))');
  } else {
      $this->_authAdapter->setCredentialTreatment();
  }
  ```

Answer (score 4):

You can update Zend_auth identity for the currently logged user. Very simplified action that updates only username could be as follows:

```
 public function editAction() {


    // check if user is logged, etc, and then
    // show the edit user form and process the data after submission.

    $userForm = new My_Form_EditUser();       


    if ($this->getRequest()->isPost()) {
        if ($userForm->isValid($_POST)) {

            // process the submitted data,
            // and when you are sure  that everything went ok,
            // update the zend_auth identity


            $authData = Zend_Auth::getInstance()->getIdentity();

            // this line would depend on the format of your 
            // identity data and a  structure of your 
            // actual form. 
            $authData->property->nickname = $formData['user']['nickname'];

            $this->_helper->FlashMessenger('Your data was changed');
            return $this->_redirect('/');
        }
    }       

    $this->view->form = $userForm;
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Hi Marcin.  For this to work the entity would need to be stored as an object.  Is that right?

Comment: @Kim. I should also work with arrays. In this example it is an object only because in my current project I store identity in such format.  But if you use arrays, than you should be able to use array notations to change the identity.

Answer (score 2):

What I really want is a method on `Zend_Auth::setIdentity($user)`.

But in the absence of such a method, I have used a hack in which I have create an auth adapter that always returns success and sets the identity to the same user object I would have created in a "real" auth adapter. Then I just call `Zend_Auth::authenticate($adapter)` with that adapter and it sets the identity internally.

Now, looking mosre closely at the internals of `Zend_Auth::authenticate()`, I see that what we could do is just:

`Zend_Auth::getInstance()->getStorage()->write($user);`

Comment: Hi David.  How would this work?  Zend_Auth has no write() method, and no __call() magic method?

Comment: D'oh! Typo. Correct is `Zend_Auth::getInstance()->getStorage()->write($user);`. Correcting answer.